# "Stream is too long" when uploading big files on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I'm trying to upload big files (4Gb) to Azure Blob Storage, but it fails. 
According to this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs), **this is my code** :

```
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("my-container-name");
blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("C:\test.avi");
```

**But I got this error**

> Message:  Stream was too long.
>   Source: System.Private.CoreLib
>   StackTrace:    at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream.d__5.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\BlobWriteStream.cs:line
>   144
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\StreamExtensions.cs:line
>   308
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line
>   301
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line
>   397
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyCompany.AzureServices.Blob.BlobService.d__7.MoveNext()
>   in C:\MyProjectSource\MyCompany.AzureServices\Blob\BlobService.cs:line
>   79
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyCompany.AzureServices.Blob.MyProject.RecordBlobService.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\MyProjectSource\MyCompany.AzureServices\Blob\MyProject\RecordBlobService.cs:line
>   25

According to this article (https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/) I try to add more option for large files.
**This is my new code** :

```
TimeSpan backOffPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
int retryCount = 1;
BlobRequestOptions bro = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
    //If the file to upload is more than 67Mo, we send it in multiple parts
    SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes = 67108864, //67Mo (maximum)
    //Number of threads used to send data
    ParallelOperationThreadCount = 1,
    //If the block fail, we retry once (retryCount) after 2 seconds (backOffPeriod)
    RetryPolicy = new ExponentialRetry(backOffPeriod, retryCount),
};
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = bro;
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
//If the file is sended in multiple parts, theses parts size are 4Mo
blockBlob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes = 4194304; //4Mo (maximum)
await blockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync("C:\test.avi");
```

**But I got the same error again** (Stream was too long).

I found in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage library that the the function "UploadFromFileAsync" use "UploadFromStreamAsync" which use a MemoryStream. I think my error come from that MemoryStream but it's write in blob storage article that the max size of a blob is 195Gb. So how I'm suppose to use it ?

I use Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 7.2.1

Thanks !

.

**UPDATE 1 :** Thanks to Tom Sun and Zhaoxing Lu, I tried to use Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.
Sadly, I get an error on the "TransferManager.UploadAsync" function. I tried to google it but nothing...
Any ideas ?

**This is my code :**

```
 string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
   string filePath = @"C:\LargeFile.avi";
   string blobName = "large_file.avi";

    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

   CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
    TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;

    // Setup the transfer context and track the upload progress
    var context = new SingleTransferContext();
    UploadOptions uploadOptions = new UploadOptions
    {
        DestinationAccessCondition = AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition()
    };
    context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
    });

    // Upload a local blob
    TransferManager.UploadAsync(filePath, destBlob, uploadOptions, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

**This is the error :**
Message : One or more errors occurred. (The transfer failed: The format of value '*' is invalid..)
Source : System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace :

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   MyCompany.AzureServices.Blob.BlobService.d__7.MoveNext()
>   in C:\MyProjectSource\MyCompany.AzureServices\Blob\BlobService.cs:line
>   96
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyCompany.AzureServices.Blob.MyProject.RecordBlobService.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\MyProjectSource\MyCompany.AzureServices\Blob\MyProject\RecordBlobService.cs:line
>   25

**And the inner exception :**
Message : The transfer failed: The format of value '*' is invalid..
Source : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement
StackTrace :

> at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.d__22.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line
>   214
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.SingleObjectTransfer.d__7.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferJobs\SingleObjectTransfer.cs:line
>   226
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.d__72.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferManager.cs:line
>   1263

**And the next inner exception :**
Message : The format of value '*' is invalid.
Source : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement
StackTrace :

> at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.BlockBlobWriter.HandleFetchAttributesResult(Exception
>   e) in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\TransferWriters\BlockBlobWriter.cs:line
>   196    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.BlockBlobWriter.d__18.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\TransferWriters\BlockBlobWriter.cs:line
>   157
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.BlockBlobWriter.d__16.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\TransferWriters\BlockBlobWriter.cs:line
>   83
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.SyncTransferController.d__13.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\SyncTransferController.cs:line
>   81
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.TransferControllerBase.d__33.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferControllers\TransferControllerBase.cs:line
>   178
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.d__22.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Local\Jenkins\jobs\DM_Hotfix\workspace\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line
>   208

**And the last inner exception :**
Message : The format of value '*' is invalid.
Source : System.Net.Http
StackTrace :

> at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value,
>   Object storeValue, Int32& index)    at
>   System.Net.Http.Headers.EntityTagHeaderValue.Parse(String input)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.RequestMessageExtensions.ApplyAccessCondition(StorageRequestMessage
>   request, AccessCondition accessCondition) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Shared\Protocol\RequestMessageExtensions.cs:line
>   125    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<>c__DisplayClass116_0.b__0(RESTCommand`1
>   cmd, Uri uri, UriQueryBuilder builder, HttpContent cnt, Nullable`1
>   serverTimeout, OperationContext ctx) in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line
>   1206    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__4`1.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\WindowsRuntime\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line
>   91

**And finally my project.json :**

```
  {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core": "0.1.0-preview",
    "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement": "0.4.1",
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols": "2.0.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "MyProject.Data.Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "MyProject.Settings": "1.0.0-*",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {   
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0-*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

**UPDATE 2 (working)**

Thanks to Tom Sun, this is the working code

```
string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
     CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
      CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
      CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
      blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
      string sourcePath = @"C:\Tom\TestLargeFile.zip";
      CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("LargeFile.zip");
      // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
      TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
      // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
      var context = new SingleTransferContext
      {
          ProgressHandler =
          new Progress<TransferStatus>(
               progress => { Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred); })
       };
      // Upload a local blob
      TransferManager.UploadAsync(sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
      Console.WriteLine("Upload finished !");
      Console.ReadKey();
```

I also add

```
ShouldOverwriteCallback = (source, destination) =>
               {
                   return true;
               },
```

in the `SingleTransferContext` to overwrite a blob if it already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use  [Azure Storage Data Movement Library easily](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement) to upload  large files to Azure blob Storage.  It works correctly for me, please have a try with the following code. More info about the Azure Storage Data Movement Library  please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/) :

```
    string storageConnectionString = "storage connection string";
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    string sourcePath = @"C:\Tom\TestLargeFile.zip";
    CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("LargeFile.zip");
    // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
    TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
    // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress

    var context = new SingleTransferContext();

    UploadOptions uploadOptions = new UploadOptions
    {
        DestinationAccessCondition = AccessCondition.GenerateIfExistsCondition()
    };
    context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferStatus>(progress =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
    });
    // Upload a local blob
    TransferManager.UploadAsync(sourcePath, destBlob, uploadOptions,context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

SDK info please refer to package.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement" version="0.4.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" version="1.8.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Check the uploaded file from azure portal

[image]

**Update:**

For .net core project code:

```
     string storageConnectionString = "myStorageConnectionString";
     CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
      CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
      CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
      blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
      string sourcePath = @"C:\Tom\TestLargeFile.zip";
      CloudBlockBlob destBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("LargeFile.zip");
      // Setup the number of the concurrent operations
      TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
      // Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
      var context = new SingleTransferContext
      {
          ProgressHandler =
          new Progress<TransferStatus>(
               progress => { Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred); })
       };
      // Upload a local blob
      TransferManager.UploadAsync(sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
      Console.WriteLine("Upload finished !");
      Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but I got an error. I edit my post with errors (see UPDATE 1).

Comment: I also repro the issue with .net core project. After change the  paramter uploadOptions to null, then it works correctly. I update the new code to  answer, please have a try with updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It's working now. I add a ShouldOverwriteCallback to activate the overwrite (I will update my post). Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

We're actively looking into the issue in Azure Storage Client Library.

Please note that since UploadFromFileAsync() is not a reliable and efficient operation for a huge blob, I'd suggest you to consider following alternatives:

If you can accept command line tool, you can try [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy), which is able to transfer Azure Storage data in high performance and its transferring can be paused & resumed.

If you want to control the transferring jobs programmatically, please use [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](http://aka.ms/dmlib), which is the core of AzCopy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use Azure Storage Data Movement Library but I got an error. I edit my post with errors (see UPDATE 1).

Answer (score 0):

The original issue is fixed in version 8.0 of WindowsAzure.Storage.