# Azure Function (Python) w/ Storage Upload Trigger Fails with Large File Uploads

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Azure Function (Python) triggered from file uploads to Azure Storage. Function works fine for files up to ~120MB. I just load tested with a 2GB file and the function produced the error `Stream was too long.`

- Where is this limitation documented?
- How would I overcome it using Python?

Using `boto3` library to PUT files to AWS S3

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
        logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")

        myblobBytes = myblob.read()

        fileName = pathlib.Path(myblob.name).name

        s3 = boto3.resource(
                's3',
                aws_access_key_id="youguessedit",
                aws_secret_access_key="noyoudidnt",
        )

        response=s3.Bucket(bucketName).put_object(Key="folder/" + fileName, 
        Body=myblobBytes, ContentMD5=md5Checksum)
        
        response.wait_until_exists()
```

[image]

Comment: What library/sdk are you using in your Azure Function? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41233653/7867968) certain functions are not efficient for large file transfers into Azure Blob

Comment: Azure Python SDK. I saw that post. Looks like it focuses on .NET.

Comment: yes, but what does your code look like? The concept is probably the same

Comment: Using `boto3`. Updated OP with a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `boto3` from `put_object` to `upload_fileobj` and setup `TransferConfig` for `multipart_threshold=1024*25, max_concurrency=10, multipart_chunksize=1024*25, use_threads=True`.

Rips now!

Able to transfer 2GB in 89secs! Not bad.