# CsvHelper stream too long

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, memorystream, csvhelper

I have a problem using CsvHelper to save a large amount of data (> 2GB) to Azure Blob Storage: I get the errore "Stream was too long".
Is there anyone who can help me solve? Thanks in advance! This is my code:

```
public static void EXPORT_CSV(DataTable dt, string fileName, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            var cnStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cnStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cnStorage);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("dataexport");
            bool exists = container.CreateIfNotExists();
            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            var stream = new MemoryStream();

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                csvWriter.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" };
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
                }

                csvWriter.NextRecord();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        csvWriter.WriteField(row[i]);
                    }
                    csvWriter.NextRecord();
                }
                csvWriter.Flush();
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                log.LogInformation($"C# BatchDataExportCSVsegnalazioni START UploadFromStream  at: {DateTime.Now}");
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
                log.LogInformation($"C# BatchDataExportCSVsegnalazioni END UploadFromStream  at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("Error upload BatchDataExportCSVsegnalazioni: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225364/stream-is-too-long-when-uploading-big-files-on-azure-blob-storage

Comment: [alternative to MemoryStream for large data volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17921880/3744182) and [MemoryStream replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12713886/3744182) may also help, especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673306/3744182) by [ghord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855432/ghord) recommending [`Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved writing direct to azure blob storage using blob.OpenWriteAsync():

```
        public static async Task UPLOAD_CSVAsync(DataTable dt, string fileName, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            var cnStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cnStorage");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cnStorage);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("dataexport");
            bool exists = container.CreateIfNotExists();
            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "fileName".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

            log.LogInformation($"C# BatchExpCSVsegnalazioni START UploadFromStream  at: {DateTime.Now}");
            await WriteDataTableToBlob(dt, blockBlob);
            log.LogInformation($"C# BatchExpCSVsegnalazioni END UploadFromStream  at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError("error upload BatchExpCSVsegnalazioni: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public static async Task WriteDataTableToBlob(DataTable dt, CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        using (var writer = await blob.OpenWriteAsync())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(writer))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csvWriter.Configuration.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<DateTime>().Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" };
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                csvWriter.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
            }
            csvWriter.NextRecord();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    csvWriter.WriteField(row[i]);
                }
                csvWriter.NextRecord();
            }
            csvWriter.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error  might be due to usage of  MemoryStream for large data rather than  with the csvHelper.
See if issue maybe fixed by :

1. writing the data direct to FileStream instead of writing to memory stream.

   ```
   using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))

   // (or)

   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
      using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
               {
   ```

(or)

2. You may make use of `cloudblockblob` library  for creating files in  azure storage  by using extension methods from the assembly Azure.Storage.Blobs and namespace Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized:

Please refer [Handling Large Files in Azure with Blob Storage Streaming](https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2019/04/18/memorystream-limits-handling-large-files-in-azure-with-blob-storage-streaming/)

Ex:

```
 var stream = blob.OpenWrite()
```

Also see [Do's and Don'ts for Streaming File Uploads to Azure Blob Storage with .NET](https://trailheadtechnology.com/dos-and-donts-for-streaming-file-uploads-to-azure-blob-storage-with-net-mvc/)